# Distorted css Top for Safari

Tags: css, safari

Currently I'm trying to implement some generic tooltips with no use of javascript (based only on css). For that I use a wrapper div with a wrapper css class and the tooltip class that has certain display attributes along with some margin-top and margin-left values to leave space for the hovered element.

It works on Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari the top value seems to be multiplied by the window scrolling putting way below the tooltip.

Does anyone has an idea of the workaround required for Safari?

The css classes:

```
.generic-tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: solid thin #000;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .generic-tooltip:hover .generic-tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    transition-delay:0.75s;
}
```

This interacts with a react component:

```
interface GenericTooltip{
    style?: CSSProperties;
    text: string
}

export const GenericTooltip : React.FC<GenericTooltip> = ({style, text, children}) => {

    return <div 
        style={style}               
        className="generic-tooltip">
        <div className="generic-tooltiptext">
            {text}
        </div>
        {children}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Please also add some HTML to it so we can see the problem.

Comment: no problem. Just passed the react component that uses these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the problem doesn't have to do with margin: if I set margin to 0 the problem keeps appearing.

Changed the code to:

```
.generic-tooltiptext {
    display: none;

/*--------------------*/

.generic-tooltip:hover .generic-tooltiptext {
    display: block;
```

On the other hand, if I use display none / block as mechanism for conditional display, this "top margin" problem get's to be resolved... although the time lapse for the effect is taken out.

So there's some curious behaviour of visibility field within safari.

Comment: display none and block are better for tooltip styling. DOM elements that are `visibility: hidden` are not visible but still take up space in the DOM. `display:none` does not